# Does endogeneity imply non-identification?

Tags: endogeneity, identifiability

My understanding of identification is that it means we can uniquely determine a value of a parameter in a model, given an infinite amount of data of the variables in our model.

E.g. If we had a simple linear model:

$$
Y_i = \beta_0 + \beta_1 X_i + \varepsilon_i
$$

Identification of $\beta_1$ depends on whether we can get a unique value of $ \frac{\text{Cov}(X,Y)}{\text{Var}(X)}
$

My understanding of endogeneity is that means:

$
\text{Cov}(X_i,\varepsilon_i)\neq 0
$

Hence:

$  \frac{\text{Cov}(X,Y)}{\text{Var}(X)} = \frac{\text{Cov}(X, \beta_0 + \beta_1 X_i + \varepsilon_i)}{\text{Var}(X)}
$
$
= \beta_1 + \frac{\text{Cov}(X,\varepsilon)}{\text{Var}(X)}
$

So I don't really see how this could result in a non-unique value of this term.

But does the answer change if we re-phrase the question to be: can we identify specifically the true/causal effect of $ X$ on $Y$? Would we then have non-identification of $\beta_1$ ? Because while we would have a unique value, it wouldn't be the causal effect?

So I guess I require clarification on: is identification just about unique values of a coefficient, or is it about a unique value of the intended meaning of the coefficient in the context of the model?